# ¿Cómo contar los elementos de mi array?

Tags: javascript, array

Quiero saber cual es el numero mas grande de mi array pero cuando estaba empezando mi ciclo for quise parar antes de terminar mi ciclo pero mi di cuenta que no mostraba en la consola ningún array (de los que están dentro de mi array principal). Este es mi código.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  // You can do this!
  for(i = 0; i > arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(largestOfFour[i].length);
  }
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

¿En qué esta mal y como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No muestra nada por qué donde dice > debe decir <, además donde dice el largestOfFour debe decir arr, pero eso solo mostrará la cantidad de elementos por arreglo. Si quieres hallar el número más alto, fíjate las respuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información. Recién estoy aprendiendo a programar y me viene demasiado bien toda esta información sobre que debo poner en lugar de que, gracias de nuevo!

Comment: i > arr.length ? , tu ciclo arrancaria con 0 > arr.length , esto siempre sera falso , entonces no habra ciclo .  creo que hay empieza tu error .

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que intentas es buscar el sub arreglo con más elementos, invierte la condición de > por esta <. Luego donde pones en consola, reemplaza largestOfFour por arr.

Si buscas el el elemento más alto de los 4 sub arreglos, te dejo esto:

Puedes utilizar `Array.prototype.reduce` y `Math.max` para lograrlo.

Lo que tienes que haces es: aplanar el array y aplicar la función max sobre el resultado.

`reduce` toma un arreglo y produce un resultado único. En este caso toma los sub arreglos y los concatena para formar un solo arreglo. Luego puedes usar el operador [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator) `...` que transforma el arreglo en parámetros del método `Math.max`.

```js
var a = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

console.log(
  Math.max(...a.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b)))
);
```

También puede usar el método apply, en lugar de operador `spread` o `...`

```js
var a = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

console.log(
  Math.max.apply(null, a.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b)))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando `Math.max.apply` puedes lograrlo:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var aux =[], mayor = 0 ;
  
  // You can do this!
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    aux[i]=Math.max.apply(null, arr[i]);
  }
  mayor = Math.max.apply(null, aux);
  console.log("El mayor elemento es: "+mayor);
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de las respuestas de como encontrar el numero mayor de un array, que creo que no es lo que preguntas... el error en tu código es que el console.log deberia ser de arr[i].length
EDIT: Como indica md, la condición del bucle for debería ser < y no >

Comment: Tampoco funcionara pues está mal la condición del for en la pregunta.